# how to apply height in percentage for div id using responsive webdesing

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Hi friends. I am doing an example using responsive web design. I changed the height and width for images in div but I am not able change the div height. That is fixed and it is not changing. I don't know what is the reason. I have tried 'height:100%' but the content in that div is not showing. It is just showing the blank page. I need help regarding this issue because it is very important for me.

Comment: put your code in http://jsfiddle.net/ and link here.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! We need to see your code in order to properly assess your question. Please edit your answer to include the code or add to a jsfiddle and link to it as pravat has indicated.

Comment: What has it to do with responsive webdesign? If your div is not expanding with it's content, your HTML-syntax might be invalid. You really should add some code to your question in order to get specific and good answers.

Answer (score 2):

The height in percentages of child elements is determined by the height of it's parent element. If the parent doesn't have a set height, the child element will think as follows:

`height: 100% of nothing.` *(Nothing being the hight of it's parent element)* 100% of nothing = nothing. So it won't set a height for it.

If you set the height of your parent element *(as explained by Sheric)* to 100%, the following happens:

`height: 100% of 100 = 100%`, thus it will spawn the whole height of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

For setting height of 100%, the parent element should have a height set. Try setting 100% to the height of all the parents elements from the HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

Define your parent element `height: 100%;` and also to `html,body{height: 100%;}` then give your `height: 100%;` to child element.